# How to filter metadata in a Mongodb database with Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to do a basic filter on the metadata of all of the documents within my Mongodb database

I generated the metadata myself using the following code

```
import mongoengine as moe

db = "games"
collection = "characters"

conn = moe.connect("db", host="localhost")

metadata = {"_gameid":generated_game_id,
            "symbol":symbol,
            "extraction_date":datetime.today()
            }


my_document = {"$meta": metadata,
               "timestamp": timepoint,
               "data": mydata
               }

conn[db][collection].insert_one(my_document)
```

From here I can perform a basic query and pull data out when it is the id, or timestamp. However, when I try to perform the query on the metadata, I keep receiving `none` or `use $getfield`.

How to query the metadata and potentially the data fields?

code for querying that I use:

```
ab = conn[db][collection]

print(ab.find_one({'_id': ObjectId('65c31dc25494ef2c27c70068')})))
```

I have tried the following but all do not work correctly:

```
print(ab.find_one({'meta.symbol': "BoFV"}))
print(ab.find_one({'$meta': {"symbol":"BoFV"}}))
print(ab.find_one({'meta': {"symbol":"BoFV"}}))
print(ab.aggregate([{"$match":{"expr":{"$eq": [{"$getField":"meta.symbol"},"BoFV"]}}}]))
print(ab.aggregate([{"$match":{"expr":{"$eq": [{"$getField":"$meta.symbol"},"BoFV"]}}}]))
```

More attempts:

```
bb = {
      "field": {
        "$literal": "symbol"
      },
      "input": {
        "$getField": {
          "$literal": "$meta"
        }
      }
  }
print(ab.find_one({ '$expr': { '$eq': [ "BoFV" , { '$getField': bb } ] } } ) )
```

Comment: Try using `$getField` operator.

Comment: I tried this but it kept throwing errors as well. let me update to show

Comment: `metadata` is not a field name in your document.

Comment: I updated accordingly. Originally I had the code inputting into a field called "metadata" but in an effort to get this to work, I changed it to "$meta". Still having trouble querying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try similarly with your documents, as shown below:

Two sample documents:

```
[
  {
    "$meta": {
      symbol: "Hello",
      x: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$meta": {
      symbol: "Bye",
      x: 2
    }
  }
]
```

The query using `$getField` used to access the field name starting with `$` sign (finds the document with `$meta` field `symbol` value as "Hello").

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      "Hello",
      {
        $getField: {
          field: {
            $literal: "symbol"
          },
          input: {
            $getField: {
              $literal: "$meta"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, How to implement this in python?

Comment: You just need to add the `{ $getField: ... }` to your aggregate query. Make sure you follow Python conventions (e.g., use quotes around operators and field names). Note that aggregate returns a cursor (see PyMongo documentation for printing from a cursor). You can also use the `$expr` with the `find_one` query. @Hojo.Timberwolf

Comment: You can try this Python syntax: `find_one({ '$expr': { '$eq': [ "BoFV" , { '$getField': { ... } } ] } } )`. Use the `$getField` details from my query above (also, use the quotes around the field names and operators). @Hojo.Timberwolf

Comment: for some reason, the result keeps coming back as none. I will update the question to reflect

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf Run this query and post the specific document you are trying to find: `for doc in ab.find():
    pprint.pprint(doc)`

Comment: figured it out, the query works. I found out that part of my code was changing the type of the code. so instead of "BoFV", it became BOFV., and the query is case sensitive. Thanks a bunch

Comment: I noticed that the code doesn't seem to work with find or aggregate. Do these require different quries?

Comment: The `find` and `aggregate` queries return a _cursor_. If no document is found the cursor will be empty. The `find_one` returns a document or None (Python) if no document is found. To get a document from a cursor you need to iterate over the cursor (e.g., use a `for` loop).

Comment: This will work  to print from the aggregate: `pprint.pprint(list(ab.aggregate(...)))`. @Hojo.Timberwolf